# Require JS Optimizer with Multiple Modules: How to not mirror entire javascript directory

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I currently have four different modules set up, which all build relative to the path where my initialize file exists. The initialize file basically includes the main configuration file and then a file that sets up all of the dependencies for the single page app and initializes it. This all works fine, the only thing I don't understand is why the require js optimizer mirrors the entire js directory. I would like to just have the four module scripts in my script-build folder where all the minimized scripts exists. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT** Here is the config file in case this helps

```
({
baseUrl: '../',
preserveLicenseComments: "true",
dir: '../../Scripts',
findNestedDependencies: "true",
mainConfigFile: '../main.js',
modules: [
    {
        name: 'main',
        include: ['main', 'requireLib']
    },
    {
        name: "apps/booking",
        include: ["apps/booking"],
        exclude: ["main"]
    },
    {
        name: 'apps/tour',
        include: ['apps/tour'],
        exclude: ["main"]
    },
    {
        name: 'apps/search',
        include: ['apps/search'],
        exclude: ["main"]
    }
],
skipDirOptimize: true,
paths: {
    requireLib: 'libs/require/require'
},
include: 'requireLib'
```

})

Comment: Perhaps you should include your `r.js` config.

Comment: not sure what you mean by that.. I've updated the question to include my config file

Comment: I tried adding the r.js file to the include variable and that didn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple excludes in one regex pattern with the | operator. For example:

```
fileExclusionRegExp: /^(r|build)\.js$/
```

This excludes r.js & build.js files. Similarly you can achieve for your directory or other files.

Comment: This looks like it should work, haven't had a chance to test it out yet.. but thanks for the help here!